# How to set default realm path to App Groups directory

Tags: cocoa, swift, realm

I am trying to set the default Realm path to App Groups directory.

```
let directory: NSURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("groups.prasanna.appName")!  
RLMRealm.setDefaultRealmPath(directory.absoluteString!)  
println(RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath())
```

The app crashes with the following error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'open() failed: Operation not permitted'

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the default realm path you're setting is your container directory. You'll have to append a file name for this to work:

```
let directory: NSURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("groups.prasanna.appName")!
let realmPath = directory.path!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm")
RLMRealm.setDefaultRealmPath(realmPath)
println(RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath()) // should be realmPath
```

Comment: Thanks @jpsim. That gives me a file URL now. But the app crashes with the same exception nevertheless.

Comment: Try writing an empty file with NSFileManager to see if you have sufficient permissions: `NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)`. The app group may not have been created properly.

Comment: The issue was I need to use directory.path! rather than absoluteString.

Comment: How would you achieve this in iOS9 / Swift 2.1?

Comment: just change the second line to this: `let realmPath = directory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm").path!`

Answer (score 1):

`RLMRealm.setDefaultRealmPath()` removed at 0.97 version, you should use this : [Tim answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34431836/1290278)

```
var config = RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
config.path = realmPath
RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has changed again, now:

```
let configuration = RLMRealmConfiguration.default()
configuration.pathOnDisk = realmPath
RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefault(configuration)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin, you can do somethings like this to change default configuration path of Realm from Document to Library directory for Xamarin iOS app:

```
// Get path of Library directory first

var directoryLib = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources);

//Configure your own path

var myOwnRealmPath = Path.Combine(directoryLib, "boards.realm");
RealmConfiguration.GetPathToRealm(myOwnRealmPath);

// Change default configuration path to your own (Here I have changed to Library directory)

RealmConfiguration.DefaultConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration(myOwnRealmPath);

//Get Realm Instance from your own designed path

_realm = Realm.GetInstance(RealmConfiguration.DefaultConfiguration);
```