# Realm in App Group not storing objects

Tags: swift, realm

After struggling to [create Realm object in App Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355557/how-to-set-default-realm-path-to-app-groups-directory/27369606?noredirect=1#comment43224005_27369606), I seem to have hit the next issue.

Objects that save into Realm with no issues when in Documents directory does not seem to save when in App Groups.

```
realm.transactionWithBlock { () -> Void in  
  let testModel = TestModel(test: "xyz")    
  self.realm.addObject(testModel)  
}
```

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Did you try creating an empty file at that location to make sure the app group was created properly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355557/how-to-set-default-realm-path-to-app-groups-directory/27369606#comment43224005_27369606

Comment: Yes. App group is created properly. Realm file is also created, along with realm objects. But no records are being saved.

Comment: Can you please create a sample project for us to be able to replicate the issue? A GitHub repo works, or you can email it to us at help@realm.io

Comment: I created a simple project and data stores without issues in App Groups. I will investigate further and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find out anything interesting?

Comment: @Prasanna Got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

All mutations including adds must happen in a write transaction. Like this:

```
self.realm.transactionWithBlock() {
    self.realm.addObject(testModel)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bmunk. Yes, this addObject is inside the transactionBlock. I will update the question.

Comment: To answer your question: "No" :-) It's not a know issue.

Comment: Ha :) should I email with a sample project to help debug?

Comment: That would certainly be very helpful!